# How to get the center of a regions that are already segmented?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm currently working on my thesis and I wanted to get the center of my regions in my image. Here is the region that I use.[image]

From that regions, I wanted to get the center of it so I can give the center of a region a color from the original image.[image]

I can't think of anything on how to get the center of the regions, but I already manage to make the regions into colors from the original image, like this [image]

Can anyone help me how to find the center of the regions?

EDIT:
[I already tried to make it into pieces, but it didn't go as planned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ9ew.jpg)

Comment: That's an interesting picture for a thesis.. Just to be clear, are you trying to segment the different colored regions from 1st image you posted?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do that, then I wanted to get the center of it so I can give the region label of the color from the original image

Answer (score 0):

1. filter the matrix of your first image by value to get a binary image
2. find contours using cv2.findContours()
3. for each contour, find the center using cv2.moments()

I hope the images you put in your thesis are more... professional.

Comment: Well thank you for the answer. Also I actually wanted to use this dataset because it is about auto coloring a sketch image, and this is a challenge. Anyway thank you for the feedback.

btw, isn't binary image only for different things in the image? for example if there are oranges, apples, then it is a good way to separate things. But in my case its a region, is it still work? I actually have tried it also, and it's not so good

Comment: It's still not clear to me what exactly you want to achieve. Can you edit your post and add another image where you have drawn the expected center points?

I assumed you want to find the center of e.g. the yellow area in the top image, center points for several light green areas, then for dark green areas, etc. so I would have created one binary image for each of these shades.

Comment: Yes, it's just like what you assume there. Okay thanks, I will try it.